# Установить сессию

Tags: php

```
session_start();

var_dump(session_name());

var_dump(session_id());

var_dump(session_save_path());
```

стартую сессию, id сессии возвращает 8vc3m0usp1e9a5980s3ooj4lup4nd334

Дальше выполняю

```
session_destroy();
```

Cессия удаляется. Потом опять стартую сессию и создаётся сессия с тем же id как и первая 8vc3m0usp1e9a5980s3ooj4lup4nd334

Почему так происходит? Насколько я знаю после разрушения сессии, вызов новой будет с новым id.

Comment: какая разница с каким id, важно что там внутри..

Comment: id это уникальный номер сессии, если удаляется старая и создаётся новая, то должно быть уникальное название сессии, а у меня постоянно одно и то же имя сессии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идентификаторы могут совпадать, о чем и сказано в мануале (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-id.php прочтите замечание, а именно: "Замечание: При использовании сессионных cookie, указание id для session_id() приводит к тому, что при вызове session_start() всегда будут отправлены новые cookie, независимо от того, совпадает ли идентификатор текущей сессии с вновь установленным."). Никакого нарушения безопасности в этом нет.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.